# Removing subdocument from specific Document keeps failing, Mongoose, MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to remove a subdocument from a specific document in my app, however I'm not recieving the expected results. The data is stored in the following format:

```
    {"_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54bb",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "manchester",
    "products": [
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54bf",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test01",
        "category": "cat1",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c0",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test02",
        "category": "cat1",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c1",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test03",
        "category": "cat2",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c2",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test04",
        "category": "cat2",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54bc",
    "__v": 0,
    "name": "leeds",
    "products": [
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54bf",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test01",
        "category": "cat1",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c0",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test02",
        "category": "cat1",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c1",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test03",
        "category": "cat2",
      },
      {
        "_id": "59fc7eccf0579ad8882b54c2",
        "__v": 0,
        "urn": "test04",
        "category": "cat2",
      }
    ]
  }
```

With there being multiple regions, and the same products stored within each. I want to be able to remove a product from each region, but keep it in the rest of the regions.

I've tried the following:

```
    const item = await Region.find({ "_id": req.params.reg }).populate('products', null, {
    _id: { $in: req.params.id }}).exec();
    await item[0].products[0].remove()
    await item[0].products[0].save();
    res.json(item);
```

However this removes the product from all of the regions. I also attempted to use $pull on Update(), in the following format but I cannot get this to work.

```
    await Region.update({ "_id": req.params.reg }, { "$pull": { "products": {"_id": req.params.id  } } });
    res.redirect("/regions");
```

Here, the redirect works correctly and there are no errors. If I console.log the output from this I receive the following:

```
{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

Any advice or pointers would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out, adding my answer as a reference in case anyone else gets stuck with this.

Region.update({ _id: req.params.reg }, { $pull: { "products": req.params.id } }

Was the code that worked for me here.

Hope this helps if anyone else finds a similar issue!